# Twitter with c# and searching

Tags: c#, xml, web-services, api, twitter

I can use the following to return an xml of users based on keyword.

```
string search = HttpUtility.UrlEncode("ladygaga");
            string xml = _oAuth.oAuthWebRequest(
            oAuthTwitter.Method.GET,
            "http://api.twitter.com/1/users/search.xml", "q=" + search);
```

The query will return an xml of users who's "name" or "screen_name" contains "ladygaga".

I have a couple of questions, firstly is it possible to query twitter with the above function and search also through the users bio (in the returned xml this has the tag "description"), in such a way that the xml will return users who have "ladygaga" in their Bio(description) as well/instead of their name and screen_name.

Secondly, the xml returned is only 1 page of results, how could I get the next bunch of returns for the query, i.e the second page?

THank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for reading the bio of each user you have to parse the result of the xml (the one with the list of followers for example) and then ask for the single user's xml.
For the next bunch of records twitter use a cursor as an int reference. So when you call the api you pass the cursor to get the next or previous page of result set.
Anyway there is a nice c# library, maybe it can simplify your work 
[linq2twitter](http://linqtotwitter.codeplex.com/)

Comment: hi, but the search function I am using (HttpUtility.UrlEncode("ladygaga");
            string xml = _oAuth.oAuthWebRequest(
            oAuthTwitter.Method.GET,
            "http://api.twitter.com/1/users/search.xml", "q=" + search); It only returns 1 page of results, which means I could only see the bio of users returned by my query, i want several pages...

Comment: If there are more the one pages for your result in the xml you should get a node similar to "NextCursor" and "PrevCursor" if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: Ok I'm going to do a bit of Googling

Comment: here you should find all the info [http://dev.twitter.com/doc](http://dev.twitter.com/doc)